# Retrieving row corresponding to minimum value in an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, min

I got the following dataframe

```
data <- structure(list(node_number = 1:8, 
                        x = c(2L, 80L, 36L, 57L, 33L, 76L, 77L, 94L 
                              ), 
                        y = c(62L, 25L, 88L, 23L, 17L, 43L, 85L, 6L 
                              ), 
                        node_demand = c(3L, 14L, 1L, 14L, 19L, 2L, 14L, 6L)), 
                   .Names = c("node_number", "x", "y", "node_demand"), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

  node_number  x  y node_demand

1           1  2 62           3
2           2 80 25          14
3           3 36 88           1
4           4 57 23          14
5           5 33 17          19
6           6 76 43           2
7           7 77 85          14
8           8 94  6           6
```

To split the hub and the list of available nodes I do the following:

```
hubs <- data[keep <- sample(1:8, 1, replace = FALSE),]

client_nodes <- data[-keep, ]
```

I now need to select two client nodes randomly

```
random_client_a <- client_nodes[seleccion <-sample(nrow(client_nodes), size = 1, replace = FALSE),]
random_client_b <-client_nodes[sample(nrow(client_nodes[-seleccion]), size = 1, replace = FALSE),]
```

And calculate the distance between the hub and the client using the following formula (which I need to minimize):

```
euc.dist <- function(A, B){round(sqrt(sum((A - B) ^ 2)))}

a<-euc.dist(hubs,random_client_a)
b<-euc.dist(hubs,random_client_b)


min <- which.min(c(a,b))
```

Since which.min() returns the index position...Is there any way I could retrieve the `dataframe` row corresponding to the minimum value?. The reason why is that I need to keep calculating and adding distances to a variable called total_distance until the cumulative `node_demand` exceedes 30.

The process would be like this:

1. Select a node hub
2. Select two random node clients, calculate the distances between the
   hub and each one of the client nodes.
3. Select the one with the minimum distance value, add it to a variable
   called `total_distance`, then and add the node_demand corresponding
   to that node to a variable called `total_demand`.
4. Stop the loop once total_demand > 30

Could anybody give me a hand?

Many thanks!

Comment: what is `total_nodes`? is not defined anywhere

Comment: Sorry I missed that one. It's the requested number of hubs for each instance of the problem (can vary from one to five). In this case let's say its 2. I will change it now.

Comment: Several problems in your code... Your definition of `hubs` is wrong and crashes. Your definition of distance should probably focus only on x and y and ignore the ID and node demand. Then, you can play with something like `ii = sample.int(nrow(data), 3) ; i_h=ii[1] ; i_a=ii[2] ; i_b=ii[3]`  and in the end use `data[ii[1+min], "node_demand"]`

Comment: I modified the code it should work now. I got the following error trying your code `Error in 1 + min : non-numeric argument to binary operator` Im not not too sure how to fix it.

Comment: Hey there Sergi~ why not just use the ```min()``` argument instead of the ```which.min()```?? As a side note- ```c(a,b)[which.min(c(a,b))``` is the same as ```min(c(a,b))```

Comment: Can't run your code right now, but if which.min() returns a position, you can select the corresponding line in your data frame using `data[min,"node_number"]`. As for the loop, use `while(total_demand <= 30) { }`

Comment: Many thanks for the answers, I ended up using `minimum<-which.min()` then data[min,"node_number"] and it worked well :)